# Adding a timestamp when specific data is entered from another sheet in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BAWAuHgwdyiXhcQ22XRL0Ilwz4MLBlR-qwIXCmYfsi4/edit?usp=sharing) containing two sheets, one named Form and the other Data. Information on the Data sheet is usually entered via the Form sheet, where a button click on the Form sheet sends the data over to the bottom row on the Data sheet.

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a timestamp to the appropriate cell in column E on the Data sheet when a cell on the same row in column D receives the word 'CLEANED' either as a submission from the Form sheet or as a direct manual entry on the Data sheet.

This code currently adds the timestamp, but only when I change a value in column D directly on the Data sheet (not when values are added via the Form sheet), and it adds the timestamp for any value that's added.

```
var ColumnToCheck = 4;
var DateTimeLocation = [0,1];
var sheetName = 'Data'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName ) { 
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if( selectedCell.getColumn() == ColumnToCheck) { 
  var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DateTimeLocation[0],DateTimeLocation[1]);
  dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

I am using this code to transfer data from the Form sheet:

```
function submitData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

var values = formSS.getRange("B2:B5").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).setValues([data]);
formSS.getRange("B2:B5").clearContent()
}
```

What would be the best way to have the date added automatically when only the word 'CLEANED' is entered? The date shouldn't clear if the word 'CLEANED' is removed or changed to a different word.

## **EDIT - SOLUTION**

Thanks to Sourabh Choraria, I was able to change my UPDATE function to this in order to incorporate my needs (my additions to his code are commented):

```
function submitData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

var values = formSS.getRange("B3:B6").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })

var statusValue = formSS.getRange("B6").getValue();   //added

if (statusValue != 'CLEANED') {                       //added
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).setValues([data]);   //added

}                                                     //added

if (statusValue == 'CLEANED') {                       //added

var now = [new Date()];
var newData =  data.concat(now)
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5).setValues([newData]);

 }                                                    //added

formSS.getRange("B3:B6").clearContent()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `submitData()` function with the following code -

```
function submitData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

var values = formSS.getRange("B2:B5").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })

// modification begins here
var now = [new Date()];
var newData =  data.concat(now)
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5).setValues([newData]);
// modification ends here  

formSS.getRange("B2:B5").clearContent()
}
```

Basically, I'm declaring a new array variable (**now**) and concatenating it to the existing **data** array, thus forming a "newData" variable and then updating the `setValues` function to accommodate this change.

Hope this helps and thanks for sharing the view access to the sheet - I made a copy of that and tested the solution directly :)

### Edit note1

As for updating the sheet only when the dropdown selected is 'CLEANED', kindly modify your `onEdit()` function to accommodate the following **IF** condition -

```
var statusValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form').getRange("B6").getValue();
if (statusValue == 'CLEANED') {
  // update timestamp as required
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it works great for all data being entered via the Form sheet, but it doesn't add a date if I edit column D on the Data sheet directly unless I also keep my existing onEdit code. Would it work to combine these two scripts? Did you have any thoughts on how best these scripts might only run if the data entering column D is the word 'CLEANED'?

Comment: My bad, should've mentioned it in my answer but yes, please use the `submitData()` function in combination with your already existing `onEdit(e)` function - per my understanding of the current setup, that's exactly how its being used too.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for explaining - although I am still struggling with only having the date entered on the Data sheet if cell B5 on the Form sheet contains the word 'CLEANED', any thoughts on how this might be done?

Comment: @J.Kubassek - i apologize again for not picking that up earlier; have updated my answer and added **Edit note1** that basically requires you to amend your `onEdit()` function and add an **IF** statement to only update date stamp when the status is chosen as 'CLEANED'. hope this helps but do please let know in case it doesn't.

Comment: No worries and thank you for that, but I actually require the data to always be submitted regardless of the value in B6, and then only add the date if B6 contains the word 'CLEANED'. I did manage to make your edit work by integrating it into the UPDATE function, but I am not sure I did this the most efficient way - if you could take one final look at the edit to my question, I would appreciate your thoughts. Thank you again!

Comment: @J.Kubassek - glad that you were able to incorporate the code :) I don't see any error, though I do see that you are still writing the values, even when `statusValue != 'CLEANED' `. I'm hoping that that's what you require too and if so, everything does look good. Do please test it out before we close it here.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look! I will in fact always need to write values, but when `statusValue != 'CLEANED'` then the date _should not_ be added, and when `statusValue == 'CLEANED'` then the date _should_ be added, which is how I set it up, and which is how it is now working.

Comment: Ah! I understand it now. In that case, this is perfect :) Do please let know in case there's anything more that ought to be done here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200566/discussion-between-j-kubassek-and-sourabh-choraria).